# Financial Data Analysis with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance, bitcoin

I would like to perform data analysis. Indeed I would like to analyze the potential correlations between the price of CAC40 and Bitcoin. For that I did data scrapping and I was able to import the values of CAC40 and Bitcoin over the last two years. Here is the script below using the yahoo finance package.

```
import yfinance as yf

cac='^FCHI'
data=yf.Ticker(cac)
dataDF= data.history(periode='1d', start='2020-1-1', end='2022-1-1')
dataDF

btc='BTC-USD'
data2=yf.Ticker(btc)
dataDF2= data2.history(periode='1d', start='2020-1-1', end='2022-1-1')
dataDF2
```

I get 6 columns (date, open price, higher price, lower price, close price, volume) for CAC40 and for Bitcoin.
Now I would like to analyze thoses results.
**Could you give me the histogram and correlation graph scripts to highlight my results?**

I have already done that :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataDF['Close'].plot()
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !!

Comment: Did you try something like `dataDF['Close'].plot.hist()`?

Comment: Yes I did thanks, but now I would like to have the correlation graph between the two columns "Close"

Comment: anyone to help me ?

Comment: You might try an internet search for "matplotlib pandas correlation graph between two columns".  What did you try? Where did you get stuck?   Do you need a professional programmer to do the programming for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can load both into the plot and then show it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataDF['Close'].plot()
dataDF2['Close'].plot()
plt.show()
```

and/or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataDF['Close'].plot.hist()
dataDF2['Close'].plot.hist()
plt.show()
```